# is there any way to connect non certified bluetooth printer?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, tsc

I have a tsc tdp 225 printer (with bluetooth accessory) that is not certified with apple. so it does not support connection directly as bluetooth printer but is there any way to connect it using core bluetooth? I need only connectivity not for print.
I have tried it with light blue app but that also not getting discover it. Any iphone and ipad device not getting discover it but mac and android easylly getting connection with it. any help will appreciated.

Comment: core bluetooth only connects to BLE devices.

Comment: any thing else that you want to suggest?

Comment: are you looking for a MFi certified bluetooth receipt printer?

Comment: yes it is mfi printer

Comment: well i have an app that is currently using StarMicronics SM-S220. It's MFi certified.

Comment: so can i connect printer?

Comment: @koropok please add an answer

Comment: yes you can connect to the printer through the Bluetooth settings of the device. you can find more information here https://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx